# Does the implementation of the java.util.Iterator use the State pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, state-pattern

I am just looking for a reasonable answear how implementation of

```
java.util.Iterator
```

is coming under State Design Pattern

**EDIT**

Please Refer the below Link

[Examples of GoF Design Patterns in Java's core libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)

Comment: I think, that you should take a look on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns/2707195#2707195).

Answer (score 3):

That, I am not sure. As far as I know, its an implementation of [Iterator Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern).

However, it can, wrongly, be said that it uses `State Pattern`, as calling `next()` affects the state of the `Iterator` object. But, IMO, its not really a `State Pattern` implementation, as it doesn't change the base object on which operation has to be executed. Wikipedia is having a fine Java example of [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern#Java).

Answer (score 2):

To quote from [the GoF book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns%3a_Elements_of_Reusable_Object-Oriented_Software):

> State: Allow an object to alter its behaviour when its internal state changes. The object will appear to change its class.

This definitely does not sound like an Iterator. Neither are these two patterns mentioned as related in the book, btw.